# css animation on sidebar close

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

In this stackblitz, I am not able to add animation while closing, I tried it using transform, but it didnt seem to work
HTML
Blocker is used to covering the full screen in a half-transparent mode in mobile devices

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
sidebar.querySelector('.blocker').onclick = hide;

function show() { // swipe right
  sidebar.classList.add('visible');
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

function hide() { // by blocker click, swipe left, or url change
  sidebar.classList.remove('visible');
  document.body.style.overflow = '';
}

function toggle() {
  sidebar.classList.contains('visible') ? hide() : show();
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  /* it's a mobile sidebar, blocker and content */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  /* to cover the whole screen */
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  /* to override the default padding */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  /* half transparent background */
  display: none;
  z-index: 99999;
  /* to be on top of any other elements */
}

.sidebar.visible {
  display: block;
}


/*cover the whole screen and to detect user click on background */

.sidebar .blocker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


/* user content */

.sidebar .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  left: -50%;
  /* will be animated to left: 0, by animation */
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide {
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="blocker"></div>
  <div class="content">
    Sidebar Content
  </div>
</div>
```

With the above code, you can have a working sidebar.

Check the working code from stackblitz

https://allenhwkim.medium.com/mobile-friendly-sidebar-in-few-minutes-7817b5c5239f
https://stackblitz.com/edit/medium-sidebar-1-eevvax?file=style.css,index.js

Comment: so what exactly you want to happen?you want it to slide back when closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate between `display:block` (when `.sidebar` has `.visible` applied to it) and `display:none` (when `.visible` is removed from `.sidebar`).

`display:none` turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements (i.e. `.blocker` and `.content`) also have their display turned off.

The reason you get an animation upon adding `.visible` is that `.sidebar` now "exists" and so `.sidebar-content` also exists and as such animates. As soon as you remove `.visible`, `.sidebar` ceases to exist again and so it and its descendants disappear instantaneously.

You are along the right lines using transforms but you need to remove `display:none` as the method for hiding the sidebar. Something like the below is a good starting point. You may need to change some values to get it looking exactly as you wish. I have added [a working codepen to show the result](https://codepen.io/andrewCodepens/pen/yLKrxWW).

```
.sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   padding: 0;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
   z-index: 99999;

   transform: translateX(-100%); // new property - will move the element off the left hand side of the screen
   transition: transform .5s ease-in-out; // new property - will make the sidebar slide in in a similar manner to your animation
}

.sidebar.visible {
   transform: translateX(0); // new property - makes sidebar sit in its natural position (i.e. taking up the whole viewport)
}

.sidebar .blocker {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.sidebar .content {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: #FFF;
   height: 100%;
   width: 250px;
}
```